# Medir el tiempo de ejecución de un Programa en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo ciertas dudas sobre cómo medir el tiempo de ejecución correctamente (programa que debe incluir procedimientos) en C# y quisiera saber si es que lo hice bien, ya que el realmente no estoy convencido de ello.
Ya que necesito comparar cada resultado por muy minuscula que sea la diferencia entre los números ingresados.

Pero lo que realmente requiero saber el método indicado para medir el tiempo de ejecución de todo el programa, aquí un fragmento del mismo:

```js
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FIterativo
{
class Program
{
    static void FibonnaciIterativo(int n)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        if (n < 0) throw new Exception("El parámetro debe ser positivo");
        long ultimo = 1, penultimo = 1;
        for (int k = 2; k <= n; k++)
        {
            long temp = penultimo; penultimo = ultimo; ultimo = ultimo + temp;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("El número {0} de la sucesión de Fibonnaci (via iterativa) es {1}", n, ultimo);

        TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", ts);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEntre el número a buscar de Fibonnaci (Precione Enter para salir)");
            string s4 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (s4.Length == 0) break;
            int k = Int32.Parse(s4);

            FibonnaciIterativo(k);

        } while (true);
    }
}
}
```

**Actualización**: Lo hice más pequeño para que fuese más ententible.
Pero mi problema surge cuando quiero medir el tiempo, solo me sale "00:00:00", y yo necesito que al menos me muestre algún milisegundo.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(1); lo que hace es deneter o Dormir por Xtiempo el proceso en este caso tu aplicacion, existe un Componentene dentro de .NET que se llama TIMER, aun que este se vera afectado si tu programa se queda colgado en algun proceso ... si no mal recuerdo tendrias que hacer delegalos para trabajarlos como procesos independientes

Comment: El stopwatch es el metodo correcto. cual es el problema con el? el timer se usa para otra cosa, nada que ver con esto. El sleep no se para que lo pusiste. en realidad esta mal la logica de tu programa. tenes que hacer un start y un stop entre los metodos que queres medir, y quedarte con ese tiempo. Si podes explicar mejor que parte necesitas medir podemos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Para que otra cosa utilizarias el timer si no para medir ? timer tiene las funciones de Start & Stop  ... e insisto el Thead.Sleep lo utilizas para suspender temporalmente la Aplicacion y o el Proceso que lo haya invocado

Comment: Ya veo, pues debería intentarlo medirlo nuevamente.
Pues lo que requiero es medir el tiempo en que se demora el programa en ejecutarse por completo,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La elección de StopWatch es correcta. Es la clase indicada para este tipo de trabajos, es ligera y muy útil.
Solo Falta que pongas a correr el StopWatch:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
```

O puedes hacerlo en una sola línea:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

Un emplo más completo sería:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); // Creación del Stopwatch.
sw.Start(); // Iniciar la medición.

// haces tus cosas acá...

sw.Stop(); // Detener la medición.
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", sw.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff")); // Mostrar el tiempo transcurriodo con un formato hh:mm:ss.000
```

Comment: Solo te falto explicar como obtener la duración; es decir el tiempo trascurrido entre que lo inicio y detuvo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, realmente se me pasó por alto ello.

Supongo que así puedo sacar el tiempo transcurrido entre el inicio y el final, pero me gustaría estar seguro, podrías por favor confirmarlo;


+stopwatch.Stop();
+Console.WriteLine("Tiempo del proceso: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
+stopwatch.Restart();

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo más completo, de la forma como generalmente uso esta clase, no es tan complejo...